# Swift 3 - set the key when appending to array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this array where I set the keys on the creation. Now in some point in my view I load some more information based on ids (the keys).

```
var colors = [
    "37027" : UIColor(red:150/255, green:57/255, blue:103/255, alpha:1),
    "12183" : UIColor(red:234/255, green:234/255, blue:55/255, alpha:1),
    "44146" : UIColor(red:244/255, green:204/255, blue:204/255, alpha:1)
]
```

I want to add more colors to this array dynamically. How can I insert new items in the array setting the key? Something like

```
colors["25252"] = UIColor(red:244/255, green:204/255, blue:204/255, alpha:1)
```

The line above doesn't work, it is just to illustrate what I need.

Thanks for any help

Update: the code above is an example. Below the real code:

```
var placedBeacons : [BeaconStruct] = []

        BeaconModel.fetchBeaconsFromSqlite(completionHandler: {
            beacons in

            for item in beacons{
                self.placedBeacons["\(item.major):\(item.minor)"] = item
            }
        })
```

Error: `Cannot subscript a value of type '[BeaconStruct]' with an index of type String`

Comment: You don't have an array, you have a dictionary. And I see no reason why that assignment shouldn't work; does it crash? Or not add the value?

Comment: What type of array is placedBeacons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the key subscripting

```
self.placedBeacons["\(item.major):\(item.minor)"] = item
```

you have to declare `placedBeacons` as dictionary rather than an array

```
var placedBeacons = [String:BeaconStruct]()
```

It requires that `item` is of type `BeaconStruct`

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote, it should work. I have used such kind of code and was able to implement successfully. I just tested your code in my end and it's working for me. I declared colors variable globally in my class file and in view did load method added the second code  to add another item in my colors array. After printing it out. My output shows full list of array with 4 items and the number of array count return 4 as well.

Please let me know, more details of your scenario so i can help you to figure it out the issue. but looks like it should work.

Comment: OK, the code was just an example. I updated the question with the real code